# How to access an XML element without a namespace

Tags: xml, ballerina

The following code snippet works and prints `<bar xmlns="x">bar</bar>` as expected:

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    final xml x1 = xml `<foo xmlns="x">
        <bar>bar</bar>
    </foo>`;

    xmlns "x" as x;
    io:println(x1[x:bar]);
}
```

However if there is no XML namespaces involved, as in the code snippet below, I get an unexpected compilation error: `undefined symbol 'bar'`.

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    final xml x1 = xml `<foo>
        <bar>bar</bar>
    </foo>`;

    // compilation error: undefined symbol 'bar'
    io:println(x1[bar]);
}
```

How do I access an XML element when there is no namespaces ? E.g. `xmlns "" as x;` is a compilation error too.

I'm using Ballerina 1.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [] syntax without using a xml namespace prefix you can use the string literal to specify with element you want. This is called expanded form where you prefix the namespace wrapped in curly braces. When you don't have a namespace defined you can ignore the namespace prefix and just use the element name.

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    final xml x1 = xml `<foo>
        <bar>bar</bar>
    </foo>`;

    // simple element name
    io:println(x1["bar"]);

    final xml x2 = xml `<foo>
        <ns:bar xmlns:ns="ns.uri.com">bar</ns:bar>
    </foo>`;

    // xml element name in expanded form
    io:println(x2["{ns.uri.com}bar"]);
    // We can also define the namespace prefix and use it to access
    xmlns "ns.uri.com" as ns;
    io:println(x2[ns:bar]);
}
```

Comment: Ok - this looks similar to how one can access e.g. JSON name/key with a space. I tried several alternatives but missed the quotes !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your particular version of Ballerina, but try this:

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    final xml x = xml `<foo>
        <bar>bar</bar>
    </foo>`;


   xml x1 = x.selectDescendants("{}bar");
    io:println(x1);
}
```

My output:

```
<bar>bar</bar>
```